Optimization of my spark dataproc cluster job
Below is my dataproc job log to process around 50GB of data
Logs:
Time spent in Driver vs Executors
Driver WallClock Time    129m 50s         80.96%
Executor WallClock Time  30m 32s        19.04%
Total WallClock Time     160m 23s
Minimum possible time for the app based on the critical path (with infinite resources)   156m 08s
Minimum possible time for the app with same executors, perfect parallelism and zero skew 130m 38s
If we were to run this app with single executor and single core                          06h 11m
Total cores available to the app 304
OneCoreComputeHours: Measure of total compute power available from cluster. One core in the executor, running
for one hour, counts as one OneCoreComputeHour. Executors with 4 cores, will have 4 times
the OneCoreComputeHours compared to one with just one core. Similarly, one core executor
running for 4 hours will OnCoreComputeHours equal to 4 core executor running for 1 hour.
Driver Utilization (Cluster idle because of driver)
Total OneCoreComputeHours available                            812h 37m
Total OneCoreComputeHours available (AutoScale Aware)           41h 27m
OneCoreComputeHours wasted by driver                           657h 53m
AutoScale Aware: Most of the calculations by this tool will assume that all executors are available throughout
the runtime of the application. The number above is printed to show possible caution to be
taken in interpreting the efficiency metrics.
Cluster Utilization (Executors idle because of lack of tasks or skew)
Executor OneCoreComputeHours available                 154h 44m
Executor OneCoreComputeHours used                       04h 01m        2.60%
OneCoreComputeHours wasted                             150h 42m        97.40%
App Level Wastage Metrics (Driver + Executor)
OneCoreComputeHours wasted Driver               80.96%
OneCoreComputeHours wasted Executor             18.55%
OneCoreComputeHours wasted Total                99.50%
App completion time and cluster utilization estimates with different executor counts
Real App Duration 160m 23s
Model Estimation  156m 08s
Model Error       2%
And my cluster config also i have pasted
Cluster Config:


"dataproc_cluster_config": {
    "cluster_config": {
      "master_config": {
        "disk_config": {
          "boot_disk_size_gb": 500
        },
        "machine_type_uri": "n1-highmem-64"
      },
      "software_config": {
        "image_version": "2.0"
      },
      "worker_config": {
        "disk_config": {
          "boot_disk_size_gb": 500
        },
        "machine_type_uri": "n1-highmem-64",
        "num_instances": 36
      }
    },
```
`


By above dataproc logs and cluster config
Can someone give me the optimized cluster config?

